# Data bag 'aws_opsworks_instance' not available

Tags: chef-infra, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

Does anyone have any idea why

```rb
instance = search('aws_opsworks_instance', 'self:true').first

# ...

    instance_host: instance['hostname']
```

would intermittently result in

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

on OpsWorks?

I've been searching for hours now and didn't find anything, so I am starting to think this is a byproduct, not the actual issue.

Since it happens every once in a while, I am thinking it may be a "race condition". Maybe OpsWorks takes a while to inject this, so Chef needs to be told to wait? If so, I couldn't find anything of the sort in the docs though.

Any ideas why this happens and how it can be fixed/avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpsWorks seemingly relies on instance names to identify these data bags, so since our script was requesting to create several new instances at the same time, there were some conflicts when assigning names (i.e. names were duplicated).

The issue was avoided by changing OpsWorks naming theme from `Greek_Deities_and_Titans` (e.g. hercules, zeus, poseidon) to `Layer_Dependent` (e.g. api1, api2, notifications1, notification2).

Although it may not be a definitive fix for the issue of Opsworks naming two instances with the same name, I have yet to encounter the issue using Layer_Dependent naming, so at least the chances are greatly reduced.

Answer (score 1):

this is specific for aws opswork. here is an excert from [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/data-bag-json-instance.html):

> [Chef search](https://docs.chef.io/chef_search.html) with `self:true` finds the [data bag](https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html) item that contains information related to the instance that the recipe is being executed on.

from the output in your post, `instance` is `null`, which is the value that the `search()` returns when there are no search results.

maybe running chef-client with `--log_level debug` will reveal more or try to reach for aws support team.

Comment: Yeah, I've figured as much. I've read the documentation, and it seems this data bag is injected by OpsWorks. What I didn't find is anything explaining why it seems to fail to do so ever once in a while. Any ideas?

Comment: @chrisandrew.cl: i have updated my answer, hope it will help you

Comment: I've not had the time yet to try to debug the recipes, but I will certainly do so if I didn't get a reply soon (either from AWS or SO). Thank you for your answer! :)